# View/edit tags in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

I upload photos using Picasa. In Picasa Web I can see/edit tags. Google Photos help seems not to have any mention of "tags" at all. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No.   Picasa has tags, Photos doesn't.